# How to resolve clientdependencyModule.cs not found in MVC 5

Tags: c#, svn, asp.net-mvc-5

[image]
I have upgraded my MVC 3 project to MVC 5 and when I run the application I receive ClientDependencyModule.cs` file not found runtime exception.

**How can I solve this problem ??**

*Error Description :*

An exception of type '`System.TypeAccessException`' occurred in `ClientDependency.Core.Mvc.dll` but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Attempt by security transparent method '`ClientDependency.Core.Mvc.MvcFilter.ValidateCurrentHandler()`' to access security critical type '`System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler`' failed.
Assembly '`ClientDependency.Core.Mvc, Version=1.7.0.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`' is marked with the `AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute`, and uses the level 2 security transparency model. 
 Level 2 transparency causes all methods in `AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers assemblies` to become security transparent by default, which may be the cause of this exception.

Please  let me know if I can provide any more info regarding. Any help is greatly appreciated !!!  Thank You :)

Comment: wait for next release...https://github.com/Shandem/ClientDependency/issues/23

Comment: Did you ever fix this issue?

Comment: I just uninstalled then reinstalled `Client Dependency Framework for MVC` and it fixed the issue for me :-)

Comment: you got the solution ?

Comment: Please find the solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013429/dotnetopenauth-not-working-with-mvc-5-rc