# Calling Html.Image from Razor view results in TypeAccessException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I've been struggling with this for hours now. I'm just trying to use the `Image` helper in a Razor view, and I'm getting a `TypeAccessException`.

Here is the offending line of code:

```
@Html.Image(Content.images.Profile_gif)
```

Here is the exception:

> #### Attempt by security transparent method 'Microsoft.Web.Mvc.ImageExtensions.Image(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, System.String)' to access security critical type 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString' failed.
>
> **Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details:** System.TypeAccessException: Attempt by security transparent method 'Microsoft.Web.Mvc.ImageExtensions.Image(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, System.String)' to access security critical type 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString' failed.

See below for the full stack trace.

---

This in an MVC5 app, and the problem is currently happening when I debug in Debug or Release mode in Visual Studio 2012. Much of the code comes from an MVC3 app, but I actually started out with a fresh MVC5 project and copied in the folders. I don't recall encountering this exception initially, but it seems to have crept in after some bug fixes and NuGet updates. (**Edit:** I just reverted to an older version to confirm this, but the exception still occurred, so it look like this exception has always been an issue unless my problem has something to do with IIS Express.)

Here are some of the key threads that I thought would help me but didn't:

- [Attempt by security transparent method 'WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926552/attempt-by-security-transparent-method-webmatrix-webdata-preapplicationstartcod)
- http://forums.asp.net/t/1939805.aspx
- [DotNetOpenAuth not working with MVC 5 RC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19013429/dotnetopenauth-not-working-with-mvc-5-rc)

---

Many of the suggested solutions seem to involve making sure the correct and latest NuGet packages are installed, so here is my packages.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="AutoMapper" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="BCrypt-Official" version="0.1.109" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="elmah" version="1.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="elmah.corelibrary" version="1.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Elmah.MVC" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" version="6.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="FluentValidation" version="5.5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="FluentValidation.MVC5" version="5.5.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.11.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.13.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="MailChimp.NET" version="1.1.65.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers" version="3.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data" version="3.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData" version="3.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax" version="3.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact" version="4.0.8876.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.8.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Mvc4Futures" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="MvcContrib.Mvc5" version="5.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="MvcMailer" version="4.5" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Ninject" version="3.2.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Ninject.MVC5" version="3.2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.Common" version="3.2.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost" version="3.2.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="ServiceStack.Text" version="3.9.71" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="T4MVC" version="3.10.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="T4MVCExtensions" version="3.10.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="T4Scaffolding.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebActivatorEx" version="2.0.6" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

I ran `Update-Package -Reinstall` to make sure every NuGet package was installed properly. I also tried deleting the packages folder and letting NuGet package restore download everything again. Neither of these made any difference.

---

Here are some relevant portions of my Web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>

<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="FluentValidation" publicKeyToken="a82054b837897c66" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.4.5.0" newVersion="3.4.5.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>

<system.web>
    <trust level="Full" />
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="Error.htm" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="10" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web>
```

---

Finally, here is the full stack trace from the exception:

```
[TypeAccessException: Attempt by security transparent method 'Microsoft.Web.Mvc.ImageExtensions.Image(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, System.String)' to access security critical type 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString' failed.]
   Microsoft.Web.Mvc.ImageExtensions.Image(HtmlHelper helper, String imageRelativeUrl) +0
   ASP._Page_Views_Member_ProfileLink_cshtml.Execute() in d:\Projects\Current\Tennis Club\MVC5\Solution\TennisClub\Views\Member\ProfileLink.cshtml:5
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +271
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +122
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +145
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +695
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +382
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +431
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +529
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +529
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +106
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +321
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassa.<EndProcessRequest>b__9() +44
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Wrap>b__3() +34
   System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Func`1 func) +69
   System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Action action) +123
   System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +133
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride) +1464

[HttpException (0x80004005): Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.]
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride) +3177611
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage) +76
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) +28
   System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) +19
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter) +979
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues) +112
   System.Web.Mvc.T4Extensions.Action(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, ActionResult result) +125
   ASP._Page_Views_Member_Filtered_cshtml.<Execute>b__2() in d:\Projects\Current\Tennis Club\MVC5\Solution\TennisClub\Views\Member\Filtered.cshtml:17
   System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass7.<RenderSection>b__5(TextWriter tw) +352
   System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) +42
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.WriteTo(TextWriter writer, HelperResult content) +45
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +53
   ASP._Page_Views_Shared_StandardLayouts_Index_cshtml.Execute() in d:\Projects\Current\Tennis Club\MVC5\Solution\TennisClub\Views\Shared\StandardLayouts\Index.cshtml:13
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +271
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +122
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +145
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer) +41
   System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass3.<RenderPageCore>b__2(TextWriter writer) +335
   System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) +42
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.WriteTo(TextWriter writer, HelperResult content) +45
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +53
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) +178
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +229
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +154
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +695
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +382
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +431
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +529
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +529
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +106
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +321
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9657896
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Answer (score 1):

As I was looking through the list of NuGet packages earlier, I noticed that one of the items was rather suspicious because its name contains "Mvc4" rather than "Mvc5":

```
<package id="Mvc4Futures" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

However, I didn't think it was the source of the problem because this package was a dependency of `MvcContrib.Mvc5`, and I didn't think I was (directly) using it for anything.

Well, somehow I missed this on my first investigation, but it turns out there is no `Image` HtmlHelper in ASP.NET MVC5--it is something added by `Mvc4Futures`. The namespace, `Microsoft.Web.Mvc` fooled me into thinking it was part of core ASP.NET MVC, but as of MVC5, it looks like the core namespace is `System.Web.Mvc`.

There are two solutions to the problem:

1. Just to use pure HTML:

   ```
   <img src="@Content.images.Profile_gif" />
   ```
2. Keep the code as is (with the `Image` helper), but replace the `Mvc4Futures` package the with `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Futures` package (this requires using `Uninstall-Package -force Mvc4Futures`, since `MvcContrib.Mvc5` depends on it).

**Edit**

I followed up by adding an issue on the MvcContrib project site on CodePlex requesting that the dependency be changed from Mvc4Futures --> Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Futures:

https://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/workitem/7229